# how to change the value of php variable directly in the code?

Tags: php

I would like to change the value of assigned php variable. For eg:
consider a variable as `$a = "yes";` I like to change this variable value as `$a = "no";` directly in the code by performing some action in another page.
Is it possible to achieve what i expect????

Comment: a normal variable's scope lies in same page only..

Comment: means available to do this are session, string query ,cookies or database

Comment: sorry rohit I expect the value to be changed directly in the php code itself

Comment: like $a='yes' to be changed as $a='no'

Comment: if its a same page then `$a='yes`'  line will declare a variable $a and assign it a value "yes" further `$a='no'` it will change the value of $a ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make a session in the first page like this:

```
$_SESSION['a']="yes";
```

make the second page work like this:

```
secondpage.php?a=no
```

so you used the get method to pass the variable ... and in the code:

```
<?php if(isset($_GET['a'])) $_SESSION['a']=$_GET['a'];?>
```

Comment: Arman Malekzade thanx for your answer but i like the value to be posted directly in the php code. your code changes the value dynamically but i want to change it statically......

Comment: you mean you want to write in the php file ? you can do it but it's not safe ! use fopen function ... but consider the user can then post everything he wants in your php file ! it's like a security issue !